# Resize a looping cloud image while clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Here is the code for the looping cloud, the animation loops from right to left and I would like to make the cloud resize-able when clicked on but I do not know how to do it...

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="clouds">
        <img border="0" alt="animated clouds" src="clouds.png">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function loop() {
                    $('#clouds').css({right:0});
                    $('#clouds').animate ({right: '+=1400'}, 5000, 'linear', function() {
                        loop();
                    });
                }
                loop();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I tried for resizing the cloud:

```
$("#clouds").click(function() {
    $("size").animate({"height" : "350"}, 500);
});
```

And the CSS:

```
#clouds {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:500;
    right:0px;
    top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code we animate the divisions in such a way that it animate from left to right and then right to left

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   function loop() {
    $('.bouncer').animate({'left': '500'}, {
        duration: 1000, 
        complete: function() {
            $('.bouncer').animate({left: 0}, {
                duration: 1000, 
                complete: loop});
        }});
    
    $('<div/>').text('exiting loop').appendTo($('.results'));
}
loop();

 $("#clouds").click(function() {
 console.log("click");
   $("#clouds").animate({"height" : "350"}, 500);
    });
    
   });
```

```css
.bouncer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

.results {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script>

   </head>

   <body>
  
<div class="bouncer">
  <img id="clouds" border="0" alt="animated clouds" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsi7hhTHPPcliUGlq2tVlaPu5cmw5QHJOVyQyugHTZOnqLECHLGL9S-qU">
  </div>
  
  </html>
```

Comment: Is this is your expected output?

Comment: Hello thank you very much for this code,I also messed up I havent posted the css up until now so you can also check my code out also i made a code pen link https://codepen.io/PepiLepi/pen/RZXqGj :D

Comment: What about my answer? Is it useful for you to solve your problem?

Comment: Hello again,yes it is really useful but I have one question I have been trying all day to make three more of the exact same loop,all of them under each other but I do not know how...If you could show me how to do it it would be awesome!

Comment: If it is useful for you why don't you accept this answer? Any way you said that you made a three more loop but let me know what you have modified with this code. Can you share your new code?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding,I did not create any new code because whenever i tried it ended up failing and I was asking you if you could show me how to add three more of these loops in my code.The loops do not need to be changed I just want to have 4 of the exact same loops under each other,hope you could understand me now.

Comment: @PepiLepi Just go through my [codepen](https://codepen.io/jinoshaji/pen/aLowRB). I have posted a sample code with three images. Just go through that and say Is this is the way that you want to produce your output? I didn't get the purpose of creating three more loops?. That's why i have posted the sample code here.

Comment: THANK YOU! This the output I wanted,thank you soo much! Now If I could ask you another favor,could you please also show me how to change the color of the 2nd image when hovered on,you do not have to I already asked you a lot,thank you again kind sir :D!

Comment: Just assign an ID to the second image and use the hover rule as `#secondImageId:hover{filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);;}` . Updated code is posted on [codepen](https://codepen.io/jinoshaji/pen/aLowRB)

Comment: Thank you so much for all your dedication I will learn from you and become a better programmer thank you again!!!