# I am having trouble making a looping "cloud" image resize when clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So here is the code,the cloud is moving from right to left and I would like to make it resize when clicked on also if someone knows how to change the color of the cloud when hovered on it would be pretty nice!

```
    <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
     </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="clouds">
    <img border="0" alt="animated clouds" src="clouds.png" >
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {

     function loop() {
    $('#clouds').css({right:0});
    $('#clouds').animate ({
    right: '+=1400',
    }, 5000, 'linear', function() {
    loop();
    });
    }

    loop();
    });

    </script>
    </div>
    </html>
    Also here is the code I tried using when resizing the cloud.

       $("#clouds").click(function() {
       $("size").animate({"height" : "350"}, 500);
        });

      #clouds {
       position:absolute;
       z-index:500;
       right:0px;
       top:10px;
       }
```

Comment: Is this question is same as the question that you asked early . [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142738/hello-i-am-trying-to-resize-my-looping-cloud-image-while-clicking-on-it-but-the/46143017?noredirect=1#comment79247829_46143017)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hello I am trying to resize my looping cloud image while clicking on it but the click wont register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142738/hello-i-am-trying-to-resize-my-looping-cloud-image-while-clicking-on-it-but-the)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#clouds").click(function(){
    $("#clouds").css({"height" : "350", "background-color" : "red"});
});
```

I can't see your CSS but assuming #clouds is just the cloud itself this would be one way to change the height and color of the cloud.

Also it seems your trying to apply the height change over the course of 0.5 seconds? If that's the case you can do that by adding one extra css property.

```
$("#clouds").click(function(){
    $("#clouds").css({"height" : "350", 
    "background-color" : "red", 
    "transition" : "height 0.5s"});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code Ill try out tomorrow and if your still wondering the css is there you just gotta scroll haha